# Get Tables based on user selection using DRF psycopg2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to get table names from dynamic database using drf.I this method I have some databases like test1, test2, test3. User has post the database name (test1) means to show the tables using psycopg2 connection. But I am stucking to create the rest api for this. Please give your suggestion.

Note : I don't have models for that tables also which is only connected via psycopg2 connection.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT
class TableData(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = TableSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({"success": False,"errors": serializer.errors},
                status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
        db_name = serializer.validated_data['dbName']
        try:
            con = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', host='127.0.0.1', dbname=db_name, password='test@123')
            con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;")
            tables = cur.fetchall()
            con.commit()
            cur.close()
            con.close()
            print(tables)
        except:
            raise
    def get(self):
        return Response(data.tables, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the code to the following so that it returns response retrieved from the db:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT
class TableData(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = TableSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({"success": False,"errors": serializer.errors},
                status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
        db_name = serializer.validated_data['dbName']
        try:
            con = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', host='127.0.0.1', dbname=db_name, password='test@123')
            con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;")
            tables = cur.fetchall()
            con.commit()
            cur.close()
            con.close()
            #print(tables)
            return Response(data=tables, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except:
            return Response({"success": False,"errors": 'Error occurred while retrieving data from the db'},
                status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)  # You can change the status code
```